# Get order custom post meta data for specific Emails Notifications in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I created a custom form field that gets added to the WooCommerce checkout form.  Everything is working as expected except I can't figure out how to get the custom field to output to the new order customer email (in this particular case, it is the on-hold email) - it is in the email sent to admins though.

I see that $sent_to_admin variable but I can't find anything like "$sent_to_customer".

How do I get that custom field value to output to the customer confirmation email?

Here is all my code:

```
/* Custom Field to Checkout
*********************************************************************************************/

/* Add form field to checkout form */
function playground_surfacing( $checkout ) {

   echo '<div id="playground_surfacing"><h3>'.__('Do you need Playground Surfacing?').'</h3>';
   echo 'The playset price does not include surfacing, the price for which is based on the size of your playground and type of surfacing.';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'pgo_surfacing', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'         => __('Yes, please contact me with safety surfacing information'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'pgo_surfacing' ));

    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'playground_surfacing' ); 

/* Save form field to order */
function playground_surfacing_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['pgo_surfacing']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'pgo_surfacing', esc_attr($_POST['pgo_surfacing']));
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'playground_surfacing_field_update_order_meta');

/* Output to order detail in dashboard */
function display_pgo_surfacing_admin($order){

    if (get_post_meta( $order->id, 'pgo_surfacing', true )) {
        echo '<p><strong>Playground Surfacing: Yes</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_pgo_surfacing_admin', 10, 1 );

/* Add to order confirmation email */
function display_pgo_surfacing_admin_email( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {
    if (get_post_meta( $order->id, 'pgo_surfacing', true )) {
        echo '<p><strong>Playground Surfacing: Yes</p>';
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'display_pgo_surfacing_admin_email', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**: 
If you want to target **"New order" (admin)** and **"Customer On Hold"** Order Email Notification, so I have changed the hook. In this different hooked function you will use the **`$email`** argument:

```
// Add "Playground Surfacing" to specific email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'display_pgo_surfacing_admin_email', 20, 4 );
function display_pgo_surfacing_admin_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Targetting specific email notifications: "new order" (admin) and "customer on hold"
    $email_ids = array('new_order', 'customer_on_hold_order');

    // Get your custom field
    $pgo_surfacing = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'pgo_surfacing', true );

    if ( in_array( $email->id, $email_ids ) && $pgo_surfacing ) {
        echo '<p><strong>Playground Surfacing: Yes</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Explanations for `$sent_to_admin`:**
>   In email notifications the variable argument $sent_to_admin will be `true` on the 3 notifications sent to the admin: `new_order`, `cancelled_order` and `failed_order` *(email IDs)*

Comment: I tried the above code and no emails are getting sent.  Does it completely replace my code block or in addition to?  I tried both.

Comment: @Brett I have updated everything (except your first hooked function that is unchanged)… Tested and works…

Comment: I cut/pasted exactly what you did and it doesn't work...the custom meta field isn't even getting added to the admin email.  Everything in my code works except the customer email doesn't have the custom meta, so why did you change the other functions?  Thanks.

Comment: @Brett I have tested that on 2 different servers one under woocommerce version 3.2.x and the other on Woocommerce 3.3.4 and it works on both of them perfectly…Note: in your code `$order->id` is not correct and should be `$order->get_id()` … So I have removed everything and keep just a replacement for your last function around email notifications where I have changed the hook and added some conditions… It should work for you (I hope), as it's working for me.